# Proof by series of equalities

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here’s my attempt and proving $(A-C)\cap (A \cap B) = \varnothing$ by a series of equalities but I’m not sure if I went about this right or where to go from here? Any help will be greatly appreciated.! My question is #3 under the algebraic proofs section. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqA8H.jpg)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtMFO.jpg)

Comment: Is any other information given? $C$ could just be empty, so that $(A-C)=A$ and the whole expression is just $A\cap B$. What's the exact question?

Comment: No the instructions just say to prove each claim by a series of equalities

Comment: So the question may be to show that different equations are equivalent to each other. As in, given one equation, you can arrive at the others. Could you type out the whole question?

Comment: The one you're working on is covered up in your image by the notebook paper.

Comment: (−) ∩ (∩)=∅ is the claim I have to prove algebraicly by a series of equalities -there’s no other information given

Comment: @Emily: I think that the three equations given in the question have to be shown to be equivalent. That equation alone doesn't necessarily have to be true, as coffeemath pointed out. We can only help if you show the whole question.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the question! I was mistaken in assuming that the question wasn't standalone. In that case, like Clive said, it's a typo.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the $C$ in the question is a typo and should actually be a $B$. Indeed, as coffeemath's answer suggests, the equation $(A - C) \cap (A \cap B) = \varnothing$ is not true in general.

To see why $(A - B) \cap (A \cap B) = \varnothing$ is true in general, you could maybe start by using the fact that $A - B = A \cap B^c$, and go from there:
$$(A-B) \cap (A \cap B) = (A \cap B^c) \cap (A \cap B) = A \cap (B^c \cap (A \cap B)) = \cdots \text{etc} \cdots$$

Comment: Thank you so much, I just realized there must  a typo because when I try making sets for A, B and C it doesn’t hold

Answer (score 1):

If $A=B=U$ and $C=\phi$ it becomes just $U.$ So if $U$ is nonempty the equation doesn't hold.